# How to access object instance from mocked instance method when unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In the code below where it says `foo_obj = ????`, how can I get a reference to the Foo object instance, or what could be a better approach?

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "Hey!"

    def bar(self):
        return self.hello + " How's it going?"

def side_effect_foo_bar(*args, **kwargs):
    foo_obj = ????
    return foo_obj.hello + " What's up?"

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(Foo, 'bar')
    def test_bar(self, mocked_bar):
        mocked_bar.side_effect = side_effect_foo_bar
        foo = Foo()
        self.assertTrue(foo.bar() == "Hey! What's up?")
```

Comment: **What** `Foo` object instance?!

Comment: well that method is going to run in the namespace of the object so shouldn't `return self.hello + "What's up?"` work?

Comment: @IonutHulub hmm well I get "NameError: global name 'self' is not defined", but perhaps I am doing this wrong.

Comment: @isonix It was just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this:

http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods

The trick is to add `autospec=True` in `@patch.object(Foo, 'bar', autospec=True)`.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "Hey!"

    def bar(self):
        return self.hello + " How's it going?"

def side_effect_foo_bar(*args, **kwargs):
    return args[0].hello + " What's up?"

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(Foo, 'bar', autospec=True)
    def test_bar(self, mocked_bar):
        mocked_bar.side_effect = side_effect_foo_bar
        foo = Foo()
        self.assertTrue(foo.bar() == "Hey! What's up?")
```